# Mostrar total de elementos en un gráfico de RDLC

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, reportviewer

Buenas , tengo este gráfico que realizo dentro de un reporte (rdlc) de visual studio 2013 y me muestra el siguiente gráfico , el gráfico esta bien pero solo me falta que me aparezca el % de los elementos respecto el total , es decir en este ejemplo hay 2 No y 1 Si por lo tanto seria un 66% NO Y 33% Si , pero el gráfico me aparece con este formato

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El dataset con el que relleno los datos tiene este formato , mediante este campo calculado "PresupConvertidoVenta" es mediante el cual quiero mostrar los datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El diseño del gráfico lo tengo de la siguiente forma
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mostrar los valores haz click con el botón derecho en el área del gráfico y selecciona la opción "Mostrar etiquetas de datos"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para mostrar los valores como porcentajes

Haz clcik con el botón derecho en las etiquetas y selecciona "Propiedades de la etiqueta de la serie...".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Escribe "#PERCENT" en "Datos de etiqueta"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si quieres indicar el número de decimales a mostrar no tienes más que utilizar "#PERCENT{Pn}" (donde n sería el número de decimales).
Por ejemplo si quieres números enteros utiliza "#PERCENT{P0}"

Comment: muchas gracias @Asier Villanueva muy amable

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de darme cuenta que solo me falta una cosa y es que el porcentaje de la leyenda me lo muestre con números enteros sin los decimales , para ello he probado lo siguiente sin éxito , se os ocurre como puedo solucionarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Comment: Acabo de modificar la respuesta para incluir este caso

Comment: gracias @AsierVillanueva era esto lo que necesitava